# What is the purpose of ⌘+Fn+← (Command-Function-Left) in Safari?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, shortcut

I think I've found the most secret and disappointing easter egg on Mac.
<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> (Command Function Left) in Safari goes to Apple.com; *does anyone know why, or when, this was added?* Cmd-Fn-Up and down and right don't do anything.

I couldn't find anything on this after about 10 seconds of skim-reading on google search.

BTW I was trying to do <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> (Shift Command Left) which selects everything to the left of the cursor.

Also noticed <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> (Control Command Left) does some weird right-align thing.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Just reloads (or seems to) my current home page.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's what it does. I thought it was an easter egg :(

Comment: Fn + arrow key == home/end/pg up/down

Comment: Interesting I noticed that in Keyboard viewer but did not know what it meant (the arrow keys change to different ones when you hold fn)

Comment: @SteveChambers I credited you for your research https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312533/what-is-the-purpose-of-fn%E2%86%90-command-function-left-in-safari/312535#comment-397931 thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a shortcut to go to your homepage and not an easter egg and does not necessarily open https://www.apple.com <s>but I haven't changed my homepage so in my case it does</s>.

Comment: Steve Chambers discovered this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312533/what-is-the-purpose-of-fn%E2%86%90-command-function-left-in-safari/312535#comment-396458 so credit to him